# We are cloaked in colours dim

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Who or what does the following riddle describe?

> The end of one story, the start of another
>   The dark hour before the dawn
>   In robes of black we perform this ritual
>   An event many mourn
>   At the summit of Thoth we meet
>   And as the proceedings do begin
>   One life of each is signed away
>   We are cloaked in colours dim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Graduation

The end of one story, the start of another

> It marks the end of student life

The dark hour before the dawn

> An end before a new start

In robes of black we perform this ritual

> Usually black gown are used

An event many mourn

> Many wants to remains students

At the summit of Thoth we meet

> For all the knowledge accumulated during one s student life

And as the proceedings do begin

> When the graduation start

One life of each is signed away

> Each receive a signed diploma

We are cloaked in colours dim

> For the different colours meaning (graduate, undergraduate)

Comment: Good job, I hope it wasn't too easy. My first attempt at making a riddle

Comment: Sorry, it may be a little late for a response to your comment but the reference to Thoth was extremely restrictive in the choice of possible answers. But anyway, I think it was a good first attempt. Keep up the good work.